# How to get defined value by variable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

My database tables 1 row looks like that

[image]

I'm storing all variables that used in body, in another column named `vars`. Then fetching all vars. If they are multiple, exploding by "," symbol.

What I want to do is, fetch all used vars from db, then filter them by second function `filter`. As you see, filter has, 3 inputs: `$content, $needle, $replacement` .

$content - messages body,

$needle - `%`.what we are searching for.`%`

$replacement - is var that we got from database, defined by php. For ex, if I get wsurl from database, It's already defined in my settings.php like DEFINE("wsurl", "www.yourdomain.com").

Question is, how can I send defined value as third input - `$replacement`?

```
public function genMsg($id) {
    $msgid = $id;
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT `body`, `status`, `vars` FROM `messages` WHERE `id`=?') or die(htmlspecialchars($this->db->error));
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $msgid) or die(htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    $stmt->execute() or die(htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    $stmt->bind_result($message, $status, $vars) or die($stmt->error);
    $stmt->fetch() or die($stmt->error);
    $stmt->close();
    $image = ($status == -1) ? "fail" : "success";
    if (isset($vars) && !empty($vars)) {
        if (strpos($vars, ",")) {
            $vars = explode(",", $vars);
            foreach ($vars as $key => $var) {
                $this->filter($message, $var, <HERE MUST BE DEFINED VALUE>);
            }
        } else {
            $var = trim($vars);
            $this->filter($message, $var, <HERE MUST BE DEFINED VALUE>);
        }
    }
    $data = array(
        'status' => $status,
        'message' => $message
    );
}

protected function filter($content, $needle, $replacement) {
    return str_replace("%'.$needle.'%", $replacement, $content);
}
```

Comment: Please update your question instead of posting a virtually identical one. Voting to close this as duplicate of [str_replace function issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921462/str-replace-function-issue), since the new one is better.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I got your question right.
This should help.

```
<?php
    define('TEST', 'abc');
    echo constant('TEST');
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php